# Filtering out list elements with O(n) time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a list of elements, where each element is a non-negative integer range. I want to filter the list in such a way that only largest unenclosed ranges are separated out. And I want to do this in `O(n)` manner with single loop. This list will always be sorted according to starting integer of each ranges.An enclosed range element may occur before or after the enclosing range element in the list.

**Example:**

Suppose the list that I have is `{[0-12],[5-15],[5-20],[10-20],[11-30],[25-42],[28-40]}`. In this list, ranges `[5-15]` and `[10-20]` fall within `[5-20]` range so I need to discard them. Similarly range element `[28-40]` is discarded as it falls within range `[25-42]`. 
I want to do this filtering using a single loop to achieve `O(n)` time complexity.

Would it be possible to achieve this ? If not, what is the best way to do filtering with complexity more than `O(n)`. A solution in Java would be great.

Comment: What guarantees do you have about the order that the list will be presented to you in -in your example, it is ordered by `start, end` - will that always be so? What do you want to do with partially overlapping ranges, eg `1-6, 3-8` ?

Comment: The elements in the list are ordered only by start of the range. Partial overlap is not filtered out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23887686/1225328

Comment: Using an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) guarentees O(nlogn).

Comment: @SteveBenett This will also filter out (and merge elements) for example [0,5],[5,10],[4,7] - and from my understanding, nothing should be filtered in this example.

Comment: You can do O(n) assuming they are sorted by start value, my merging the consecutive ranges which over lap.  When they no longer overlap, you move on to the next one.

Comment: Well, once merged, these ranges actually end into a single `0-42` big range, right? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

An element could swallow previous one if they have the same range start but bigger or equal end. Also the element could swallow next if the next one's range end less than current eleemnt's end.

So you go through the list and compare current and next elements.

If they have the currentStart=nextStart and nextEnd>=currentEnd -> remove current.

else If nextEnd<=currentEnd -> remove next.

Comment: It might be helpful to give a short proof of correctness.

Answer (score 0):

in pseudocode, merging periods can be done like that:

```
def merge(l:list[period], e:period):
    if l == nil:
        return list(e)
    else:
        lh = l.head
        ll = l.tail
        if e.end < lh.start: 
            return e::l // original list prepended with e
        else if lh.end < e.start:
            return lh::merge(e,ll) // head + trying to merge period with the tail
        else: //overlap, make new period from e and list head and merge it with tail
            newstart = min(e.start, lh.start)
            newend = max(e.end, lh.end)
            return merge(period(newstart,newend), ll)
```

In your case, you have to diff i/o merge, but the idea is similar.