# algorithm of counting Overlaps of ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

input integer is always positive

input: `[[1, 4], [3, 7], [6, 8], [10,15]]`
output: `[[1, 8], [10,15]]`

input: `[[3, 4], [1,3], [5, 9], [5, 12]]`
output: `[[1, 4], [5, 12]]`

I read this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887686/javascript-array-of-ranges-reduction), but wandering if there is a better way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Describe the problem in more detail, in as much specific detail as you can. All you've done so far is give a couple of test cases. Work your way through those test cases and how you might solve them. Describe exactly what it is you're looking for in the input, what output should be generated, and what you could do to transform the input into the output. If you work through that problem fully, you may find that you have created an algorithm to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the data ascending and then check the predecessor if it fits into the last range. If not append the actual array to the result set.

```js
function groupRanges(array) {
    return array
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a[0]- b[0] || a[1]- b[1]; })
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1] || [];
            if (a[0] <= last[1]) {
                if (last[1] < a[1]) {
                    last[1] = a[1];
                }
                return r;
            }
            return r.concat([a]);
        }, []);
}

console.log(groupRanges([[1, 4], [3, 7], [6, 8], [10,15]]));
console.log(groupRanges([[3, 4], [1,3], [5, 9], [5, 12]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For every start and end of range make a pair containing value and `+1/-1` for start and end

Sort these pairs by value, using `+-1` as secondary key in compare function: `(x,+1) before (the same x,-1)`

Make `ActiveRanges=0`, walk through pair list/array, adding `+-1` to `ActiveRanges`.

When `ActiveRanges` becomes nonzero, big range begins.

When `ActiveRanges` becomes zero, big range finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, usint the MathJS library to generate ranges :

```js
let input = [[1, 4], [3, 7], [6, 8], [10,15]]

let workArray = input.map( arr => math.range(arr.join(":"), true )._data )
workArray = [].concat.apply([], workArray) // Concatenating all values
workArray = [...new Set(workArray)] // Deduplicating, sorting

let output = [],
 min = workArray[0],
 max = min

for( let i=0, l=workArray.length; i<l ; i++){
 if(max+1 != workArray[i+1]){
  output.push([min,max])
  min = workArray[i+1]
  max=min
 } else {
  max++ 
 }
}

console.log(output) // [ [1,8] , [10,15] ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.13.1/math.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is of length 4 (as per your example) and everything is constant as you described it, here is a simple function you can use:

```
function reGroup(arr) {
    const x = [arr[0][0], arr[2][1]];
    return [x, arr[3]];
}
```